# ghostscript not working in php

Tags: php, pdf, ghostscript

I want to create php page which convert first page of pdf file to jpg image.
I have these code.

exec('convert -density 300 "24.pdf"[0] "24-1.jpg"', $output);
print_r(array_values($output));

It not work.
I have tested following code(with command prompt and php) and it works well.
Exec('DIR', $output);
print_r(array_values($output)); //to check command

Exec('convert', $output);
print_r(array_values($output)); //to check imageMagick

Exec('convert -transverse 22.jpg 22-1.jpg', $output);
print_r(array_values($output)); //to check imageMagick function

But when I tried this command

Exec('convert -transverse 22.pdf[0] 22-1.jpg',$output);
print_r(array_values($output)); //to check imageMagick function with pdf

It not work but all above command is working with command prompt.
It seems that imageMagik working well but ghostscript have problem with php.
Please can you tell me why ghostscript is not working with php.

I'm using
Window 7 Ultimate, IIS7.5 and PHP 5.3.
ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16
ghostscript 9.10

Thanks and regards
Mohammed Shaikh

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your code - some of the quotes in your PHP were incorrect; you need to use `'`.

Comment: I have tried all the code in command prompt it work. But and in php well. But when I include pdf(which involve ghostscript) it not work in php. I think php has a problem with ghostscript.

Comment: Have you tried using full paths everywhere?

Comment: Yes I have tried but same thing happen.
When i used exec('dir') it shows my directory.

Comment: What's the filepath for `convert`?

Comment: I can't understand this. Convert work without filepath, filepath of imagemagik is included in envinment.

Comment: It's included in your environment. PHP is run by the webserver, which has its own environment, so it's best to put a full path in so you can be sure it can find the file.

Comment: When i used transverse with image it works in php(it is 2nd last in my question). But only pdf file not processed. Images are processed.

Comment: Can you run your PHP code from the command line? Does it work then? You've presumably got a difference in environment variables between your user account and the webserver's account

Comment: Yes, It works through command line, but not in server.

Comment: Then you need to configure the server so the environment settings are the same.

Comment: How? Where is server environment setting.

Comment: You need to make sure that the environment settings for your user account and for the account that the web server runs under are configured in the same way.

Comment: Thnanks both of you.
The convert method of imagemagik not worked, but ghostscript method using gswin32c worked after including ghostscript path in system path.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
exec("<full path to binary> '-dNOPAUSE' '-sDEVICE=jpeg' '-r<resolution>'
     '-g<dimensions>' '-dUseCIEColor' '-dTextAlphaBits=4' '-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4'
     '-o<where you want the image stored>' '-dJPEGQ=<quality - I used 90>'
     '<pdf file to resize>'", $outputArray);
```

If the placeholders are filled in using variables, the variables - like `$resolution` - just go straight in to the command, e.g. `-r$resolution`.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i've tryed using imagmagick to extract the first image from PDF using convert but 
it didn't work so i used Ghostscript with the below script and it works perfectly in the webserver :

```
gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -o d:/output.jpg -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -dNOPAUSE -dJPEGQ=100 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -r150 -dUseCropBox -dUseTrimBox d:/input.pdf
```

However after testing many ghostscript ver, even the latest ones, i found out the 9.06 is the most stable ghostscript ver

Answer (score 0):

The key part of craned's correct answer is 'full path to binary'.
For some reason Apache is not getting the windows PATH environmental variable, the solution I've found was to write the complete path to the gs executable between double quotes if it has spaces in it .